# Reporting Q2 2011 new caching feature questions

Tags: caching, telerik, reporting

I'm trying out the new Q2 2011 version 5.1.11.713 features.
I keep reading the "Whats new" section and I'm seeing talk about these new caching features; however I am a little confused.

Does caching only work when using the WCF Reporter Service Implementation?
Can I use the caching features with the standard ASP.net web viewer control?
Will caching work in an out of proc session state set up?

I've been searching through documentation and i can't seem to find hardly any on these subject.

My reports are larger reports and are throwing out of memory exceptions when running in out of proc session (web farm).
I've read numerous forum post on these issue and have read the design considerations. 
Just wanted to look into the caching options to maybe reduce these errors, but i can't find any documentation or guide on the caching topics.
I would like some more information if anyone could help. 
Any information regarding caching or memory exceptions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Caching is a part of report engine. Whenever report is to be rendered, the data retrieved is stored in cache and then rendered according to rendering extensions. You get out of memory exception because the cache is out of memory and data retrieved from database is larger than the cache of report engine. You will get more information here:
http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/designing-reports-life-cycle.html
http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/configuring-telerik-reporting-session-state.html